# Constructor call in kotlin using vararg

Tags: java, constructor, kotlin

Is there any way to call a constructor using varargs without hard coding the array parameter (`datain[0]`, `datain[10]`, etc.). For example,

```
constructor(vararg datain:String): this(datain[0],datain[1],datain[2]){
}
```

Currently I am calling like this:

```
public class parent(var var1:String, var var2:String){
}

public class child(var var3:String, var1:String, var2:String): parent(var1,var2){
    constructor(vararg datain:String): this(datain[0],datain[1],datain[2]){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems a bit meaningless since `vararg` can contain more or less items than the other constructor expects. Also, it's quite a rare situation when all of the arguments have the same type so that the `vararg` would suite. But no, there's currently no language feature which would decompose `vararg` into function or constructor call non-vararg parameters.

I suppose, it's better for language design to make you show it explicitly that you choose certain items of `vararg` as it contains no hidden pitfalls and you will always be aware of indexing.

But what you can is pass a `vararg` parameter as a `vararg` parameter to another function or constructor, may be, having transformed it. It's done by **spread operator** `*`, see the example:

```
public class V(vararg s: String) {
    constructor(vararg s: Int): this("a", *s.map(Int::toString).toTypedArray(), "b")
}
```

Any array of the right type can be passed using `*` (including `vararg` itself since it's an array), but it's what the power of `vararg` ends with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am creating object using reflection
  var requestObject = constructor.newInstance(args)
Can you please suggest me how to pass args to get a new object as its type is  vararg and at run time for different class I have different number of parameters.

Comment: @manish, as I found just now, you can do what you want through reflection:
`val ctor = javaClass<YourClass>().getConstructor(...)` and then
`ctor.newInstance(*yourVararg)`.